Disable CORS in Django running in Dokku
When building websites I use the following logic:
If my frontend domain is domain.com then my backend domain is always api.domain.com (subdomain via Cloudflare)
I hit an errors caused by CORS
WildcardOriginNotAllowed,
MultipleAllowOriginValues when I tried to apply response CORS header via nginx,
Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header
In my Django config I have added:
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
    "DELETE",
    "GET",
    "OPTIONS",
    "PATCH",
    "POST",
    "PUT",
]
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_HEADERS = True
SECURE_CROSS_ORIGIN_OPENER_POLICY = None

In my Cloudflare config I disabled all the advanced security settings.
In my Dokku config I don't have any settings related to CORS.
The problem remains after all the fixes

did you add midddleware...?
